# how to cite using emacs+auctex+reftex

Tags: citing, emacs, auctex, reftex

I recently switched from TeXStudio to Emacs/AUCTEX. The problem is that I don't know how to cite a paper. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,apabackref=true,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\bibliography{p-dbase.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{Here is where I want autosuggestion on my papers' list to be appeared}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like for any other macro you want to insert in AUCTeX, you should use <kbd>C-c RET</kbd> `cite` <kbd>RET</kbd> (or <kbd>C-c C-m</kbd> `cite` <kbd>RET</kbd>; for more information about autocompletion in AUCTeX see [the quick start](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Inserting-macros) or [Completion section](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Completion) of the manual).  This works also for all other citation macros provided by `natbib`, `biblatex`, ect... (`\citep`, `\citealt`, `\parencite`, `\textcite`, etc...)

For the particular case of bibliography commands, you may want to take advantage of the great package RefTeX.  AUCTeX has a basic support for bibliographic commands also without RefTeX, but this package provides a far superior completion.

In order to automatically start RefTeX when you open a LaTeX file add the following code to your init file

```lisp
;; Turn on RefTeX in AUCTeX
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
;; Activate nice interface between RefTeX and AUCTeX
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
```

In this way, you can still insert a `\cite` command with <kbd>C-c RET</kbd> `cite` <kbd>RET</kbd>, but you can also use the key-binding <kbd>C-c [</kbd>.  RefTeX overtakes the task to provide completion of bibliographic entries, but you can continue using the usual AUCTeX-way to insert macros.

Answer (score 8):

The command you need here is `reftex-citation`, which is bound to `C-c [` by default. There is more info in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/reftex/Creating-Citations.html#Creating-Citations)

Alternatively, you can use [helm-bibtex](https://github.com/tmalsburg/helm-bibtex) in place of reftex. Helm-bibtex is more powerful, but it lacks a few features that reftex has, such as allowing you to [search your records on different fields](https://github.com/tmalsburg/helm-bibtex/issues/62).

Comment: when i use `C-c [` the terminal says that `command  is undefined`

Comment: You need to turn on reftex with `(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)`, see the manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex/AUCTeX_002dRefTeX-Interface.html#AUCTeX_002dRefTeX-Interface)

Comment: @Yorgos You can also use `C-c c` if you add `(setq reftex-extra-bindings t)`

Comment: @ppr Thanks for that tip.  It is quite usefull on a MacOS computer---easier to reach :-)