# Emacs, AUCTeX, RefTeX and biblatex's multicite commands

Tags: biblatex, emacs, auctex, reftex

I've been giving a chance to Emacs (with AUCTeX and RefTeX), but I'm still stumbling quite a lot. I've gotten the hang (and appreciated) the RefTeX way to add a citation (as described in, e.g. [how to cite using emacs+auctex+reftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295304/105447)). Also, I'm a biblatex user, and recent versions of AUCTeX provide good support for it. However, somehow, how to make this work for biblatex multicite commands (`\cites`, `\textcites`, `\parencites` and so on) completely eludes me.

None of the multicite commands is available out of the box in the `reftex-citation` menu <kbd>C-c [</kbd> (though I suppose they could be added without great difficulty). The relevant multicite commands do show up in autocompletion through <kbd>C-c C-m</kbd>, but then I do not get the nice regex search in the bib file (as far as I can tell. See more below, it works for regular cite commands but not for multicite).

Furthermore, syntax highlighting (fontification) only recognizes the first key of a multicite command.

Also, RefTeX's `reftex-view-crossref` <kbd>C-c &</kbd>, does not seem to work with multicite commands, returning "Not on a crossref macro argument".

Related to this, if I want to add an extra bibkey to an already existing multicite command, I also cannot access reftex facilities (with a regular cite command, placing the point before the citation command's closing brace and calling <kbd>C-c [</kbd> would offer me a regex search on the bib files. This can also be used to add a citation key with a command inserted with <kbd>C-c C-m</kbd>).

`biblatex.el` does seem to include "Support for multicite commands"/"Qualified Citation Lists", but I can't find my way through it.

Am I missing something? Is there a proper "RefTeX way" to deal with biblatex's multicite commands?

In particular:

1 - What would be the normal way (that is, considering default configuration) to add one such command?

2 - How to make these commands recognized by RefTeX, so that `reftex-view-crossref` works and new keys can be added with RefTeX facilities after the citation command has already been inserted?

Besides that, but less important:

3 - How to add, e.g. `\cites` to RefTeX menu on the call to <kbd>C-c [</kbd>?

4 - How to make fontification work for all the keys of a multicite command?

In case someone is willing to play with the relevant settings, a MWE ("biblatex-examples.bib" should be in the same directory as the document, for things to work without further configurations):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{sigfridsson}

\parencites{sigfridsson}{knuth:ct}

\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

[In case it is relevant, I'm using Emacs 24.5 with AUCTeX 12.1.1]

Comment: Further exploration showed me that things work as expected out of the box (except for fontification) for `\cites` or `\Cites` but the behavior described above holds for `\textcites`, `\parencites`, `\footcites` or `\autocites`.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, maybe ask at the auctex mailing list, see here: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/auctex

Comment: @KeksDose, thank you for your suggestion. If indeed no one comes by here, I'll attempt that. But in due time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many questions here so I try to stay brief.  I presume that you have these lines in your init file:

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
```

**1 -** What would be the normal way (that is, considering default configuration) to add one such command?

RefTeX provides the variable `reftex-cite-format`.  You can use it for custom query when you hit <kbd>C-c [</kbd>.  With AUCTeX, you have to set `LaTeX-reftex-cite-format-auto-activate` to `nil` when setting `reftex-cite-format`.  In your case, try:

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-reftex-cite-format-auto-activate nil)

(setq reftex-cite-format
      '((?\C-m . "\\cite[][]{%l}")
        (?s    . "\\cites[][]{%l}")
        (?p    . "\\parencites[][]{%l}")
        (?P    . "\\Parencites[][]{%l}")))
```

in your init file.  But I find the input interface in the document cumbersome: You have to do <kbd>C-c [</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, go through the regex query, mark each entry and hit <kbd>A</kbd>.  But that's a matter of taste.

**2 -** How to make these commands recognized by RefTeX, so that reftex-view-crossref works and new keys can be added with RefTeX facilities after the citation command has already been inserted?

This is the tricky part.  You have to patch the functions `reftex-figure-out-cite-format` and `reftex-view-crossref`.  Put this in your init file and restart Emacs; the original `string-match` lines are commented for your reference:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "reftex-cite"
(defun reftex-figure-out-cite-format (arg &optional no-insert format-key)
  "Check if there is already a cite command at point and change cite format
in order to only add another reference in the same cite command."
  (let ((macro (car (reftex-what-macro 1)))
        (cite-format-value (reftex-get-cite-format))
        key format)
    (cond
     (no-insert
      ;; Format does not really matter because nothing will be inserted.
      (setq format "%l"))

     ((and (stringp macro)
       ;; (string-match "\\`\\\\cite\\|cite\\'" macro))
           (string-match "\\`\\\\cite\\|cite\\(?:[s*]\\|texts?\\)?\\'" macro))
      ;; We are already inside a cite macro
      (if (or (not arg) (not (listp arg)))
          (setq format
                (concat
                 (if (member (preceding-char) '(?\{ ?,))
                     ""
                   reftex-cite-key-separator)
                 "%l"
                 (if (member (following-char) '(?\} ?,))
                     ""
                   reftex-cite-key-separator)))
        (setq format "%l")))
     (t
      ;; Figure out the correct format
      (setq format
            (if (and (symbolp cite-format-value)
                     (assq cite-format-value reftex-cite-format-builtin))
                (nth 2 (assq cite-format-value reftex-cite-format-builtin))
              cite-format-value))
      (when (listp format)
        (setq key
              (or format-key
                  (reftex-select-with-char
                   "" (concat "SELECT A CITATION FORMAT\n\n"
                              (mapconcat
                               (lambda (x)
                                 (format "[%c] %s  %s" (car x)
                                         (if (> (car x) 31) " " "")
                                         (cdr x)))
                               format "\n")))))
        (if (assq key format)
            (setq format (cdr (assq key format)))
          (error "No citation format associated with key `%c'" key)))))
    format)) )

(with-eval-after-load "reftex-dcr"
(defun reftex-view-crossref (&optional arg auto-how fail-quietly)
  "View cross reference of macro at point.  Point must be on the KEY
argument.  When at a `\\ref' macro, show corresponding `\\label'
definition, also in external documents (`xr').  When on a label, show
a locations where KEY is referenced.  Subsequent calls find additional
locations.  When on a `\\cite', show the associated `\\bibitem' macro or
the BibTeX database entry.  When on a `\\bibitem', show a `\\cite' macro
which uses this KEY. When on an `\\index', show other locations marked
by the same index entry.
To define additional cross referencing items, use the option
`reftex-view-crossref-extra'.  See also `reftex-view-crossref-from-bibtex'.
With one or two C-u prefixes, enforce rescanning of the document.
With argument 2, select the window showing the cross reference.
AUTO-HOW is only for the automatic crossref display and is handed through
to the functions `reftex-view-cr-cite' and `reftex-view-cr-ref'."

  (interactive "P")
  ;; See where we are.
  (let* ((macro (car (reftex-what-macro-safe 1)))
         (key (reftex-this-word "^{}%\n\r, \t"))
         dw)

    (if (or (null macro) (reftex-in-comment))
        (or fail-quietly
            (error "Not on a crossref macro argument"))

      (setq reftex-call-back-to-this-buffer (current-buffer))

      (cond
       ;; ((string-match "\\`\\\\cite\\|cite\\*?\\'\\|bibentry" macro)
       ((string-match "\\`\\\\cite\\|cite\\(?:[s*]\\|texts?\\)?\\'\\|bibentry" macro)
        ;; A citation macro: search for bibitems or BibTeX entries
        (setq dw (reftex-view-cr-cite arg key auto-how)))
       ((string-match "\\`\\\\ref\\|ref\\(range\\)?\\*?\\'" macro)
        ;; A reference macro: search for labels
        (setq dw (reftex-view-cr-ref arg key auto-how)))
       (auto-how nil)  ;; No further action for automatic display (speed)
       ((or (equal macro "\\label")
            (member macro reftex-macros-with-labels))
        ;; A label macro: search for reference macros
        (reftex-access-scan-info arg)
        (setq dw (reftex-view-regexp-match
                  (format reftex-find-reference-format (regexp-quote key))
                  4 nil nil)))
       ((equal macro "\\bibitem")
        ;; A bibitem macro: search for citations
        (reftex-access-scan-info arg)
        (setq dw (reftex-view-regexp-match
                  (format reftex-find-citation-regexp-format (regexp-quote key))
                  4 nil nil)))
       ((member macro reftex-macros-with-index)
        (reftex-access-scan-info arg)
        (setq dw (reftex-view-regexp-match
                  (format reftex-find-index-entry-regexp-format
                          (regexp-quote key))
                  3 nil nil)))
       (t
        (reftex-access-scan-info arg)
        (catch 'exit
          (let ((list reftex-view-crossref-extra)
                entry mre action group)
            (while (setq entry (pop list))
              (setq mre (car entry)
                    action (nth 1 entry)
                    group (nth 2 entry))
              (when (string-match mre macro)
                (setq dw (reftex-view-regexp-match
                          (format action key) group nil nil))
                (throw 'exit t))))
          (error "Not on a crossref macro argument"))))
      (if (and (eq arg 2) (windowp dw)) (select-window dw))))) )
```

I tried this with this file and you see where it works and where not:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-bib.bib}
@book{lamp:94,
  author    = {Leslie Lamport},
  title     = {LaTeX - {A} Document Preparation System: User's Guide
               and Reference Manual, Second Edition},
  publisher = {Pearson / Prentice Hall},
  year      = {1994},
  isbn      = {978-0-201-52983-8},
  timestamp = {Fri, 08 Apr 2011 18:21:00 +0200},
}

@book{mitt:97,
  author    = {Michel Goossens and
               Sebastian Rahtz and
               Frank Mittelbach},
  title     = {The LaTeX Graphics Companion - Illustrating documents
               with TeX and PostScript},
  series    = {Addison-Wesley series on tools and techniques
               for computer typesetting},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year      = {1997},
  isbn      = {978-0-201-85469-5},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-bib.bib}

\begin{document}

%% =============== RefTeX standard

\cite{mitt:97}
==> \verb|C-c &| Ok, \verb|C-c [| Ok

\cites[Pre][Post]{mitt:97}[Pre][Post]{lamp:94}
==> \verb|C-c &| Ok, \verb|C-c [| Ok

\footcitetext[Pre][Post]{mitt:97}
==> \verb|C-c &| NOk, \verb|C-c [| NOk

\parencite*[Pre][Post]{mitt:97}
==> \verb|C-c &| Ok, \verb|C-c [| NOk

\parencites{mitt:97}
\parencites(GPre)()[Pre][]{mitt:97}[Pre][]{lamp:94}
\parencites(pre)()[pre][]{mitt:97}
\parencites(post)[post]{mitt:97}
==> \verb|C-c &| NOk, \verb|C-c [| NOk

%% ============== RefTeX patched

\parencites[Pre][Post]{mitt:97}[Pre][Post]{lamp:94}
==> \verb|C-c &| Ok, \verb|C-c [| Ok

\parencites(GPre)(GPost)[Pre][Post]{mitt:97}[Pre][Post]{lamp:94}
==> \verb|C-c &| NOk, \verb|C-c [| NOk

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

The patches don't work when global optional arguments in `()` are present.  Therefore, you have to patch the function `reftex-what-macro` as well; but that would be beyond tex.sx.  Please drop a line to `bug-auctex@gnu.org`.  These issue should be fixed in Emacs 27.

**3 -** How to add, e.g. `\cites` to RefTeX menu on the call to <kbd>C-c [</kbd>?

Check point 1.

**4 -** How to make fontification work for all the keys of a multicite command?

I'm afraid this is a "won't fix".  Fontification is done by `font-latex.el` shipped with AUCTeX which in general can only fontify fixed number of arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It goes a long way already! I've been quite impressed with the overall setting of Emacs + AUCTeX + RefTeX, but it is indeed somewhat daunting (especially for the non initiated in lisp). I will drop a line  to `bug-auctex@gnu.org` regarding the global optional arguments. But I had to ask first, as someone new to this "parallel universe" I assumed it was something I missed.

Comment: ArashEsbati, as to fontification, I've tried `"parencites" "*[[{[[{[[{[[{[[{[[{"` and it seems to work most of the time. Do you see any negative side effects of using this?

Comment: Sorry, correcting: `"parencites" "(([[{[[{[[{[[{[[{[[{"`.